# Google enhanced conversions

Tags: magento2

is there a way without setting up a Magento 2 extension, Google enhanced conversions and Google Tag Manager.
Google Tag Manager, got set up but I don't know exactly how to set it up in magento!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to set up Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce tracking in Magento 2 without using a Magento 2 extension or Google Tag Manager. Here are the steps to do so:

1. Log in to your Google Analytics account and enable Enhanced Ecommerce tracking for your website.
2. In Magento 2, go to Stores > Configuration > Sales > Google API and enter your Google Analytics Tracking ID in the Account Number field.
3. In Magento 2, go to Stores > Configuration > Sales > Google API > Google Analytics and enable the following options:

- Enable Universal Analytics
- Enable Enhanced Ecommerce

4. In your Magento 2 theme, open the file app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/templates/html/head.phtml and add the following code after the  tag:

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">    
         window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];    
         function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}    
         gtag('js', new Date());    
         gtag('config', '[GA_TRACKING_ID]');   
    </script>
   ```

Replace [Vendor] and [Theme] with your own theme's name, and replace [GA_TRACKING_ID] with your Google Analytics Tracking ID.

5. In your Magento 2 theme, open the file app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addto.phtml and add the following code to the end of the file:

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var productData = {
         'id': '<?php echo $product->getId(); ?>',
         'name': '<?php echo $product->getName(); ?>',
         'price': '<?php echo $product->getFinalPrice(); ?>',
         'brand': '<?php echo $product->getAttributeText("manufacturer"); ?>',
         'category': '<?php echo $product->getCategory()->getName(); ?>',
         'variant': '<?php echo $product->getSku(); ?>'
        };
        gtag('event', 'view_item', productData);
    </script>
   ```

This code will track product views and send the data to Google Analytics. You can modify the productData object to include more product attributes if needed.

6. In your Magento 2 theme, open the file app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage/success.phtml and add the following code to the end of the file:

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php $order = $block->getOrder(); ?>
   <?php $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems(); ?>
   var orderData = {
    'id': '<?php echo $order->getIncrementId(); ?>',
    'affiliation': '<?php echo $this->getStoreName(); ?>',
    'revenue': '<?php echo $order->getGrandTotal(); ?>',
    'tax': '<?php echo $order->getTaxAmount(); ?>',
    'shipping': '<?php echo $order->getShippingAmount(); ?>',
    'coupon': '<?php echo $order->getCouponCode(); ?>',
    'currency': '<?php echo $order->getOrderCurrencyCode(); ?>',
    'products': [
        <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
            {
                'id': '<?php echo $item->getSku(); ?>',
                'name': '<?php echo $item->getName(); ?>',
                'price': '<?php echo $item->getPrice(); ?>',
                'quantity': '<?php echo $item->getQtyOrdered(); ?>'
            },
           <?php endforeach; ?>
           ]
        };   
    </script>
   ```